# Three buttons, three different actions/outputs

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-intent

This is my first post here and I'm very new to programming. I have this assignment where we are supposed to have three different buttons doing three different things.

1. The First button is kind of doing what I want. Which is change the text.
2. The Second button is supposed to open a new activity where it should be a picture. (I've done this assignment before and that worked, but when together with something else it didn't work.)
3. The Third button is supposed to open a new activity, and there should be a grid view with 6 pictures.

Here the first XML file and java file. Which after several tries is the easiest (I think) way to start to just make sure I'm able to press the buttons and open the next activity (on button 2 and 3). As you see there are many tries, don't want to delete anything since I'm not sure of what I'm doing. So this is a combo of different tries...
Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eee"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/text_edit"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:background="#005622"
    android:text="Change text"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_edit2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="När du klickar på den här knappen &#xA; så kommer dess text att bytas ut."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_edit" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:text="Naturens underverk"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_edit2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activitytext2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Klicka här så får du &#xA; se något väldigt vackert."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="#ff3111"
    android:text="Till sida 2"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activitytext2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activitytext3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Feelings..."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity3" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="left" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="top" />

<!--<Fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name=".com.example.lab2.mainactivity"
    android:layout_width="match-parent"
    android:layout_height="match-parent"
    />

<Fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name=".com.example.lab2.mainactivity"
    android:layout_width="match-parent"
    android:layout_height="match-parent"
    />
-->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



enter code here
package com.example.lab2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.service.autofill.OnClickAction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
//Jag har så fruktansvärt många olika varianter jag testat nu så vill bara börja om...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

 //   private Bundle savedInstanceState;

 /*    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*/

//När användaren trycker på knappen change text så sker detta under.

Button text_edit = findViewById(R.id.text_edit);
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text_edit2);
Button activity2 = findViewById(R.id.activity2);
TextView activitytext2 = findViewById(R.id.activitytext2);
Button activity3 = findViewById(R.id.activity3);
TextView activitytext3 = findViewById(R.id.activitytext3);

text_edit.setOnClickListener(this):
activity2.setOnClickListener(this);
activity3.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.text_edit:
        text.setText("Kolla, kolla vad hon kan!");
        break;

    case R.id.activity2:
        openactivity2() {
        activity2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                openactivity2();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openactivity2() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
        break;

    case R.id.activity3:
        openactivity3() {
        activity3.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openactivity3();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openactivity3() {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        }

        break;
    }
  }


  /* private Bundle savedInstanceState;
//En del av mig vill skriva in en if-sats och länka till andra classer,
//det borde gå att sätta flera knappar på samma sida då de gör olika saker.
//Dock väldigt lång?

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_edit);
        text_edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text_edit);

        text_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText("Kolla, kolla vad hon kan!");
            }
        });

  }
}*/
/*public void opentext_edit() { 
//Är detta för att du ville ha upp en toast när du klickade in dig?
    opentext_edit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, toast_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent); //behöver kanske alla intents ha olika namn?
}


private Button activity2; vill inte radera något för tidigt så kommenterar ut de i
säkerhetsskull


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity2);
    activity2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        openactivity2();
    }
    });
 }
 public void openactivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }


private Button activity3;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activity3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3);
    activity3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            openactivity3();
        }
    });
 }
 public void openactivity3() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

  //Här nedanför sker... detta sker när vi trycker på tredje knappen?

 private GridView gridView;
  private GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this , R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

  }
  private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData(){
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources(), obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);

    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResource(), 
imgs.getResourceId(I, -1));

    }
    return imageItems;
} */
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid at all. Commenting out onCreate gives the app no entry point, You also can't findViewById in top-level variables. Misbalanced brackets alone should cause a build failure

Comment: yes I had the onCreate for a while but apparently got commented out (feels like I've tried 100 different ways), I put it back now and had to create a field (whatever that is, we haven't had those kind of instructions). About the top-level variables, everything is basically copy/paste from a yt-clip and that's how he did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, you just had some basic things wrong, I added comments to help you understand what is going on:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    //Declare views
    //You first have to declare your views (Button, TextView, EditText etc)
    Button text_edit, activity2, activity3;
    TextView text, activitytext2, activitytext3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        //Initialize views
        //You don't have to create a method when initializing your views
        //but it keeps your code in order
        initViews();

        //Set onclick listeners
        //Declare your click listeners and pass it the context of you activity "this"
        text_edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        activity2.setOnClickListener(this);
        activity3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        text_edit = findViewById(R.id.text_edit);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text_edit2);
        activity2 = findViewById(R.id.activity2);
        activitytext2 = findViewById(R.id.activitytext2);
        activity3 = findViewById(R.id.activity3);
        activitytext3 = findViewById(R.id.activitytext3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.text_edit:
                //Set text to TextView
                text.setText("Kolla, kolla vad hon kan!");
                break;
            case R.id.activity2:
                //Start Activity2
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case R.id.activity3:
                //Start Activity3
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
    }
 }
```